# Why list of String has no forEach method?

Tags: java, arrays, string, foreach

I have problem with understand why `String[] args` variable has no `forEach` method? I can not find any information that this type is not Serializable or Collection because `forEach` methos implements Serializable.

For example, I have simple main Java class. If I want to use `forEach` method, I have to first import `Arrays` class and then on `stream` use `forEach` method like below:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Arrays.stream(args).forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}
```

Why it is not possible to make it just simple like this?

```java
args.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: `args` is an array, not a `List`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Short answer: Arrays don't have a `forEach` method defined on them.

Longer answer: Because it doesn't need it. An array type (using `[]`, not `List<>`) represents a low level structure in memory, more suited to low level optimisations rather than higher level functional-style code. The hardware of a machine much more closely resembles the imperative, stateful style from languages like C, rather than the functional stateless style from languages like Haskell. Because of this, when creating a lower level data structure like a basic array, it doesn't necessarily make sense to give it more advanced functionality. If you really want a `forEach()` method, trivially wrap it using `Arrays.asList()`, `Arrays.stream()`, or `List.of()` (depending on Java version).

Comment: I disagree with the part "Because, it doesn't need it". The language is developing, with pretty powerful Stream API and Collection API which are being significantly enhanced version by version, arrays look like dinosaurs...

Comment: You can implement handy methods without breaking the "low-level structure" idea behind it.

Comment: If you gave forEach to arrays, why not add filter, map, and other stream methods as well. Eventually you'd turn arrays into streams. While this isn't inherently bad, there isn't anything inherently bad with having "dinosaurs" that are just used to back more user-friendly interfaces. Anyways, the question was "why it has no forEach method". Because the designers of the language didn't think it was worth putting in, especially with the existence of Collection and Stream

Comment: If I were to implement it, I would add `stream()`, `parallelStream()`, `spliterator()` and `forEach()` exactly as they did it to `Collection`. It's not about cluttering arrays with `Stream`'s or `Collection`'s methods, it's more about adding helpful "transition methods" to the new language features. To me, it's more convenient to write `list.stream()` rather than `Arrays.stream(array)` and I see no point in treating arrays differently. On the other hand, I understand that it's much easier to add a bunch of overloaded methods to `Arrays`...

Comment: ... than to introduce something new at the language level. My point was that "we don't need it" (which I am highly doubting) and "we won't implement it because it's not worth it" are different things :)

Comment: I see what you mean. I guess "the Java designers think we don't need it" is more accurate

Answer (score 6):

The main method takes one parameter of type `String[]`. Which is an `Array` of `String`s.

`List`s and `Array`s are two different things and only the former does provide a foreach method.

Answer (score 5):

Not just String array, Array of any object or primitive types do not have this feature since arrays are the data stricture that is different from other collection implementations

Comment: This is probably better suited in a comment, but it is useful to note nonetheless

Answer (score 4):

> 1. The direct superclass of an array type is `Object`.
> 2. Every array type implements the interfaces `Cloneable` and `java.io.Serializable`.
>
> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html

Any array type doesn't define `forEach`.

Why?

It simply wasn't implemented and the authors apparently want to keep array types as fundamentally pure as possible.

I don't think this method would be superfluous; on the contrary, I am sure it would be very handy. It's not a trivial task, though. Think about primitive arrays and how you would implement, let's say, a `boolean` consumer. You would have to bound a plain JDK class `BooleanConsumer` to a fundamental JVM concept `boolean[]`, or to grand the interface a special status, or to generate the interface on the fly.